# Sql adding new row based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Table A(ID, col2, col3, col4)
```

I want to add a new entry to Table A for every ID given that col4 = 'certain criteria' and the value of Col2 from the existing entry will be used as col2 of the new entry. How would I go about accomplishing this task?

The part that is throwing me off is how to do this without using a loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that should work

```
INSERT INTO TableA (col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col2, 'any constant value', col4 FROM TableA
WHERE col4='certain criteria'
--GROUP BY ID (not clear if you need to group by something)
```

Comment: Col2 in my insert into statment should have the same value as COl2 from the SELECT statement from Table A. How would I modify it to fit this form?

Comment: You mean all your new rows must have 'a' in col2 ? Or did I misunderstand ?

Comment: the 'a' was formatted for your first post. This query is going add new fields to the Table A based on a filter(col4). Every value that is being inserted into Col2, is the Col2 of the already existing entry. For example Table A('1','2228','dumbo', 'circus') already exists Table A('2','23','ring', 'circus') already exists Table A('3, '2228', 'lion', 'cirus') is the new entry Table A('4','23','motorcycle', 'circus') is the new value

Comment: @MasterP my actual answer fits your needs, no ?

Comment: It does fit to a point, but the important part is adding the value from Col2.